# Black screen when trying to run the liveCD or install on an Acer 5742z

Tags: 11.04

Since the 11.04 version, on live CD or on a instalation Ubuntu doesn't work. I install it, or launch the live cd and the screen is all black, no image. I know ubuntu its runing but the screen is still black and I don't know how to fix it.

I have an Acer 5742z.

Answer (score 1):

I've had lots of issues with different hardware on the new installers. I find a lot are linked to ACPI/APIC.

Try starting the installation with the boot options modified to disable APIC first (apic=off), and then if unsuccessful, ACPI (acpi=off).

Check [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions) for more info.